# What can explain the overhead of using const in this case?

Tags: c#, performance, benchmarkdotnet

I'm banging my head against the wall here, so I hope that some of you may be able to educate me. I was doing some performance benchmarks using BenchmarkDotNet and I ran into this weird case where it seems that declaring a member `const` degrades performance considerably.

```
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;
using System;

namespace PerfTest
{
    [DisassemblyDiagnoser(printAsm: true, printSource: true)]
    public class Test
    {
        private int[] data;
        private int Threshold = 90;
        private const int ConstThreshold = 90;

        [GlobalSetup]
        public void GlobalSetup()
        {
            data = new int[1000];
            var random = new Random(42);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                data[i] = random.Next(100);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<Test>();
        }

        [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
        public void ClampToMemberValue()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                if (data[i] > Threshold) data[i] = Threshold;
            }
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void ClampToConstValue()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                if (data[i] > ConstThreshold) data[i] = ConstThreshold;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the only difference between the two test methods is whether they compare against a regular member variable or a const member.

According to BenchmarkDotNet using the const value is significantly slower and I don't understand why.

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.11.5, OS=Windows 10.0.18362
Intel Core i7-5820K CPU 3.30GHz (Broadwell), 1 CPU, 12 logical and 6 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=3.0.100
  [Host]     : .NET Core 3.0.0 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.46205, CoreFX 4.700.19.46214), 64bit RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 3.0.0 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.46205, CoreFX 4.700.19.46214), 64bit RyuJIT


|             Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev | Ratio |
|------------------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|------:|
| ClampToMemberValue | 590.4 ns | 1.980 ns | 1.852 ns |  1.00 |
|  ClampToConstValue | 724.6 ns | 4.184 ns | 3.709 ns |  1.23 |
```

Looking at the JIT compiled code doesn't explain it as far as I can tell. Here's the code for the two methods. The only difference is whether the compare is done against a register or a literal.

```
00007ff9`7f1b8500 PerfTest.Test.ClampToMemberValue()
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                 ^^^^^^^^^
00007ff9`7f1b8504 33c0            xor     eax,eax
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
00007ff9`7f1b8506 488b5108        mov     rdx,qword ptr [rcx+8]
00007ff9`7f1b850a 837a0800        cmp     dword ptr [rdx+8],0
00007ff9`7f1b850e 7e2e            jle     00007ff9`7f1b853e
00007ff9`7f1b8510 8b4910          mov     ecx,dword ptr [rcx+10h]
                if (data[i] > Threshold) data[i] = Threshold;
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
00007ff9`7f1b8513 4c8bc2          mov     r8,rdx
00007ff9`7f1b8516 458b4808        mov     r9d,dword ptr [r8+8]
00007ff9`7f1b851a 413bc1          cmp     eax,r9d
00007ff9`7f1b851d 7324            jae     00007ff9`7f1b8543
00007ff9`7f1b851f 4c63c8          movsxd  r9,eax
00007ff9`7f1b8522 43394c8810      cmp     dword ptr [r8+r9*4+10h],ecx
00007ff9`7f1b8527 7e0e            jle     00007ff9`7f1b8537
                if (data[i] > Threshold) data[i] = Threshold;
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
00007ff9`7f1b8529 4c8bc2          mov     r8,rdx
00007ff9`7f1b852c 448bc9          mov     r9d,ecx
00007ff9`7f1b852f 4c63d0          movsxd  r10,eax
00007ff9`7f1b8532 47894c9010      mov     dword ptr [r8+r10*4+10h],r9d
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                                             ^^^
00007ff9`7f1b8537 ffc0            inc     eax
00007ff9`7f1b8539 394208          cmp     dword ptr [rdx+8],eax
00007ff9`7f1b853c 7fd5            jg      00007ff9`7f1b8513
        }
        ^
00007ff9`7f1b853e 4883c428        add     rsp,28h
```

and

```
00007ff9`7f1a8500 PerfTest.Test.ClampToConstValue()
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                 ^^^^^^^^^
00007ff9`7f1a8504 33c0            xor     eax,eax
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
00007ff9`7f1a8506 488b5108        mov     rdx,qword ptr [rcx+8]
00007ff9`7f1a850a 837a0800        cmp     dword ptr [rdx+8],0
00007ff9`7f1a850e 7e2d            jle     00007ff9`7f1a853d
                if (data[i] > ConstThreshold) data[i] = ConstThreshold;
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
00007ff9`7f1a8510 488bca          mov     rcx,rdx
00007ff9`7f1a8513 448b4108        mov     r8d,dword ptr [rcx+8]
00007ff9`7f1a8517 413bc0          cmp     eax,r8d
00007ff9`7f1a851a 7326            jae     00007ff9`7f1a8542
00007ff9`7f1a851c 4c63c0          movsxd  r8,eax
00007ff9`7f1a851f 42837c81105a    cmp     dword ptr [rcx+r8*4+10h],5Ah
00007ff9`7f1a8525 7e0f            jle     00007ff9`7f1a8536
                if (data[i] > ConstThreshold) data[i] = ConstThreshold;
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
00007ff9`7f1a8527 488bca          mov     rcx,rdx
00007ff9`7f1a852a 4c63c0          movsxd  r8,eax
00007ff9`7f1a852d 42c74481105a000000 mov   dword ptr [rcx+r8*4+10h],5Ah
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                                             ^^^
00007ff9`7f1a8536 ffc0            inc     eax
00007ff9`7f1a8538 394208          cmp     dword ptr [rdx+8],eax
00007ff9`7f1a853b 7fd3            jg      00007ff9`7f1a8510
        }
        ^
00007ff9`7f1a853d 4883c428        add     rsp,28h
```

I'm sure there's something I've overlooked, but I can't grok it at this point so I'm looking for input on what can explain this.

Comment: @OlivierRogier I remember BenchmarkDotNet failing when run in Debug.

Comment: Indeed, using a stopwatch proves that using a const int is a little slower than a field on a simple a*a... even if the IL code use more operands.

Comment: Using BenchmarkDotNet 12.0 and .Net Framework 4,8, I execute the exact code from the question and don't see any meaningful difference in the results between the two methods when running in x86. I can see the observed difference when switching to x64.

Comment: The `cmp` and `mov` instructions which are used for the const path occupy more memory than a register based instructions because encoding a number requires additional bytes and in total take more CPU cycles to execute (9 bytes vs 5 bytes for `mov` and 6 bytes vs 5 bytes for cmp). And even though there is additional `mov  ecx,dword ptr [rcx+10h]` instruction for the non-const version it's most likely optimized by JIT compiler to be outside of the loop in the release version.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov But wouldn't the optimization for non-const version cause it to behave differently in parallel execution? How can compiler optimize it when the variable can be changed in different thread.

Comment: @Euphoric, in general case the compiler simply isn't aware that a variable can be modified by different threads unless it's explicitly specified by special construction like `volatile` but in that specific case it even doesn't matter as it's already done - I just overlooked that first time (the `ecx` is initialized once). So the bottom-line is that the const `cmp` and `mov` iteration instructions overweight their non-const counterparts.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/features/setup-and-cleanup.html

I believe you should be using `[IterationSetup]` instead of `[GlobalSetup]`. With global setup, the `data` is changed once and then the changed `data` is reused across benchmarks.

So, I've changed the code to use proper initialization. Changed variables to make checks more frequent. And added few more variations.

```
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;
using System;

namespace PerfTest
{
    [DisassemblyDiagnoser(printAsm: true, printSource: true)]
    public class Test
    {
        private int[] data;
        private int[] data_iteration;

        private int Threshold = 50;
        private const int ConstThreshold = 50;

        [GlobalSetup]
        public void GlobalSetup()
        {
            data = new int[100000];
            var random = new Random(42);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                data[i] = random.Next(100);
            }
        }

        [IterationSetup]
        public void IterationSetup()
        {
            data_iteration = new int[data.Length];
            Array.Copy(data, data_iteration, data.Length);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<Test>();
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void ClampToClassConstValue()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < data_iteration.Length; i++)
            {
                if (data_iteration[i] > ConstThreshold) data_iteration[i] = ConstThreshold;
            }
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void ClampToLocalConstValue()
        {
            const int ConstThresholdLocal = 50;
            for (var i = 0; i < data_iteration.Length; i++)
            {
                if (data_iteration[i] > ConstThresholdLocal) data_iteration[i] = ConstThresholdLocal;
            }
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void ClampToInlineValue()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < data_iteration.Length; i++)
            {
                if (data_iteration[i] > 50) data_iteration[i] = 50;
            }
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void ClampToLocalVariable()
        {
            var ThresholdLocal = 50;
            for (var i = 0; i < data_iteration.Length; i++)
            {
                if (data_iteration[i] > ThresholdLocal) data_iteration[i] = ThresholdLocal;
            }
        }

        [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
        public void ClampToMemberValue()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < data_iteration.Length; i++)
            {
                if (data_iteration[i] > Threshold) data_iteration[i] = Threshold;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results look more normal :

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.12.0, OS=Windows 10.0.17134.1069 (1803/April2018Update/Redstone4)
Intel Core i7-8850H CPU 2.60GHz (Coffee Lake), 1 CPU, 12 logical and 6 physical cores
Frequency=2531250 Hz, Resolution=395.0617 ns, Timer=TSC
.NET Core SDK=3.0.100
  [Host]     : .NET Core 3.0.0 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.46205, CoreFX 4.700.19.46214), X64 RyuJIT
  Job-INSHHX : .NET Core 3.0.0 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.46205, CoreFX 4.700.19.46214), X64 RyuJIT

InvocationCount=1  UnrollFactor=1

|                 Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |   Median | Ratio | RatioSD |
|----------------------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|------:|--------:|
| ClampToClassConstValue | 391.5 us | 17.86 us | 17.54 us | 384.2 us |  1.02 |    0.05 |
| ClampToLocalConstValue | 399.6 us |  9.49 us | 11.66 us | 399.0 us |  1.05 |    0.07 |
|     ClampToInlineValue | 384.1 us |  5.99 us |  5.00 us | 383.0 us |  1.00 |    0.06 |
|   ClampToLocalVariable | 382.7 us |  3.60 us |  3.00 us | 382.0 us |  1.00 |    0.05 |
|     ClampToMemberValue | 379.6 us |  8.48 us | 16.73 us | 371.8 us |  1.00 |    0.00 |
```

There doesn't seem to be any difference between different variants. Either everything is optimized or const int not optimized in any way in this scenario.

Comment: I was playing around with this as well and I think you're on to something, so thanks for the input. If the array survives between benchmarks then the branch prediction will be different between the two cases. I'll poke around some more.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen I think one main difference is that when the array survives with its values, only the first benchmark that runs has to do the work of changing the array. For all further benchmarks on the same array, the if will never be true.

Comment: @NineBerry good point. If the majority of the tests run with the altered values I still can't explain the difference, but doing iteration setup does seem to matter so there's something here to dig into. Thanks both of you!

Comment: Actually my point was not so good. Given the original code in the question, `GlobalSetup` is executed twice, one time before each Benchmark, so both methods start with the same pre-condition.

Comment: @NineBerry Yes. But each method is executed many times as way to smooth out extremes. So for each method there is one iteration that is OK and then all other iterations that behave differently.